# Command to find how much data was transferred from USB

Tags: usb, kernel, cron, scripts

How can I create a `cron` job that runs every minute and logs how much data was transferred by USB?

Ideally I want log of amount the data in bytes transfers done.

For example if i tranferred 4mb file from my pendrive to my computer system , and then 1 gb file from my computer system to pendrive ,it should log all this .

Comment: What exactly would you like to log? Meta-data of files that have been created/deleted? The contents of files? An estimate of transferred bytes for files and metadata? Do you really want to log data, or are you trying to find out what files enter/leave your computer?

Comment: cron does not feels like it is the correct method to me.

Comment: I was creating log analyser of USB devices , so i had to log as much information as available , I stuck on the amount of data in bytes transferred .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe cron itself is the correct method but [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) has native support for doing a capture on the USB interfaces. From the link:

> **Linux**
>
> To dump USB traffic on Linux, you need the usbmon module, which has existed since Linux 2.6.11. Information on that module is available in /usr/src/linux/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt in the Linux source tree. Depending on the distribution you're using, and the version of that distribution, that module might be built into the kernel, or might be a loadable module; if it's a loadable module, depending on the distribution you're using, and the version of that distribtuion, it might or might not be loaded for you. If it's a loadable module, and not loaded, you will have to load it with the command
>
> ```
> modprobe usbmon
> ```
>
> which must be run as root.

Comment: Where does information of capture goes , in which folder ?

Comment: the default is /var/log/